# Appium Test on Edit Text Clear Button On right Side

Tags: android, android-edittext, automated-tests, appium, android-drawable

I am using Appium to test my Android App. I made a Edit text with a X (clear icon) right of the text and when user click on this icon then Edit text become empty.The issue is how can I test this Click in Appium Testing.

here is my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Edit Text"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_delete"// X icon at right side of edit text
    >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

and Here is the code

```
 passwordEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
            final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
            final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
            final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (event.getRawX() >= (passwordEditText.getRight() - passwordEditText.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                    passwordEditText.setText(null);

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i don't see anything tried on appium, would like you to got through the documentation @www.appium.io

Comment: `android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_delete"// X icon at right side of edit text`  seems like there is no id properties attached to the `X` icon other than it being an icon form drawable.

Comment: yes thats the problem, I am using this icon to clear the text by setting on touch listener as shown in the code but How do I automate it thats the problem

Comment: 1. you can always use the XPATH, i believe the link to the UI automator that you have provided in one of the comments depicts there is a `View`assigned to this drawable even. 2. you can try look for it so and attach a UI automator view for that specific selsection

Comment: Sorry actually that view is divider line of height 1 dp above send button its not associated to the X image

Comment: ok cool i got your problem, lemme debug this on my end and get back to you if can with a solution

Comment: cool thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Send some text to your edit text using send keys method.. Then click on your x button and get text from edit text and verify entered text is cleared.. Is this what you wanted to verify?

Comment: I want to automate the click on x button Can I do that?

Comment: Yep! You can do that!!

Comment: How can I do that ? because x button does not have separate id

Comment: You can use xpath or name property, by class name etc.. If you could post your uiautomator view of your button, it will be helpful for me to suggest

Comment: https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/v/t35.0-12/12633146_614773635344082_2123020095_o.jpg?oh=50103c3bd2b30436b281c696a302d0d2&oe=56B0122E Link of UI automator view of button

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this problem ?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same. Has anybody found a solution for this?